# Prove/Disprove: $\dfrac{e^{2y}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{2X}]} f_X(y)$ is a probability density function

Tags: probability, density-function

**Question**:
Assume that $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function of a random variable $X$ such that $X\in[a,b]$ for $b\gt a$.

Does there exist another random variable $Y\in[a,b]$ having $\dfrac{e^{2y}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{2X}]} f_X(y)$ as its
probability density function?

---

Note: There reason I'm asking this question is that I want to treat $\dfrac{e^{2y}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{2X}]} f_X(y)$ as the pdf of a new random variable like $Y$ and somehow change the measure I'm working with (cause dealing with that $Y$ is much more simple for me in some situation). I believe the "[Radon–Nikodym derivative (density)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)" should be related to my question. However, I'm not very familiar with the probability measures.

---

**My try**:

I know that the integral of the probability density function over the whole support of the variable should be equal to $1$. So I tried to prove that:

$$
\int_{a}^{b} \dfrac{e^{2y}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{2X}]} f_X(y) dy =1
$$

However, I do not know how to deal with the fraction $\dfrac{e^{2y}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{2X}]}$ in the integral. We know that $\int_a^b f_X(x)dx=1$. I cannot see what happens when the fraction is multiplied, and how it affects the whole integral.

Comment: Sure that it's not $e^{2y}/E[e^{2X}]$?

Comment: $\mathbb E[e^{2y}]=e^{2y}$ since $e^{2y}$ is not random.

Comment: @Snoop Now it's corrected. Sorry for my mistake

Comment: Just to provide some background, this is an example of what is called [exponential tilting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_tilting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result follows from
$$\int_a^b e^{2y} f_X(y) dy = \mathbb E[e^{2X}].$$
Also note that the function is nonnegative.